# Javascript Image Not Shown When Opening New Window for Printing

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm creating an html page for printing and on that page I'm trying to attach an image, but the image is not showing.

```
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write('<div><p style="text-align: center;">Amuse Me TV</p></div>');
    newWin.document.write('<div><img src="Common/Img/avatar.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/></div>');
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
```

I'm doing this but when new window opens for printing only the first div is shown and there is no image.

The source of the image is correct.

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps the image is not fully loaded yet when you call the print method?

Comment: Yes I also think that's the problem, but how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested:

What I've done is wait until the image is loaded to call the print then close functions

```
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.write('<div><p style="text-align: center;">Amuse Me TV</p></div>');
newWin.document.write('<div><img src="Common/Img/avatar.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;" onload="newWin.print(); newWin.close();"/></div>');
```